# How does one unit test all paths of a C++ sequence (single or multiple functions or classes)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am asking for a suggested implementation to test that a function, or a set of functions, followed a certain path.  This will provide a reasonable way to check state and ensure errors are handled in the exact methodology desired and intended.  I am looking for unit test framework independent discussion.

Suggestions?

I've sketched up a current concept as a starting point for thought.

Note: this example is extremely simplified.  And looks like a trivial case, but it easily extends into more complicated checking.

Integer tracking of a code path in the example could be replaced with strings as desired, and it's pretty easy to get more extravagant from here, but I wanted to gather other's takes on what could be done, before continuing.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QVector>

#define RUN_TEST

#ifdef RUN_TEST
#define inheritTestableOnly : public Testable
#define inheritTestableToo  , public Testable
#define appendCodePath(a) addCodePath(a)
#else
#define inheritTestableOnly
#define inheritTestableToo
#define appendCodePath(a)
#endif

class Testable
{
public:
    void addCodePath(qint64 newCode)
    {
        codePath.append(newCode);
    }

    void clearCodePath()
    {
        codePath.clear();
    }

    QVector<qint64> const & getCodePath() const
    {
        return codePath;
    }

private:
    QVector<qint64> codePath;
};




class ToTest inheritTestableOnly
{
public:
    ToTest(){}
    virtual ~ToTest(){}

    void testFunction(bool pathSelect1, bool pathSelect2)
    {
        bool pathSelect3 = false;

        if(pathSelect1)
        {
            if(pathSelect2)
            {
                appendCodePath(1);
            }
            else
            {
                appendCodePath(-2);
                pathSelect3 = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            appendCodePath(-1);
        }

        if(pathSelect3)
        {
            qDebug() << "Success!";
            appendCodePath(2);
        }
    }
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ToTest t;
#ifdef RUN_TEST
    t.testFunction(true, true);
    qDebug() << t.getCodePath();
    t.clearCodePath();
    qDebug() << t.getCodePath();

    t.testFunction(false, false);
    qDebug() << t.getCodePath();
    t.clearCodePath();
    qDebug() << t.getCodePath();

    t.testFunction(true, false);
    qDebug() << t.getCodePath();
    t.clearCodePath();
    qDebug() << t.getCodePath();
#else
    t.testFunction(true, true);
    t.testFunction(false, false);
    t.testFunction(true, false);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Output when RUN_TEST is defined:
QVector(1)
QVector()
QVector(-1)
QVector()
Success!
QVector(-2, 2)

Output when RUN_TEST is not defined:
Success!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no magic button anywhere that one can push, and a perfect unit test pops out, for any chunk of code. Each individual class and application is unique, and will require one to come up with its own individual set of unit tests, that will be implemented in a manner that's tailored to that class or application.

Comment: The question is how would one describe the "intended path"? Wouldn't that be as much complicated and error-prune as the program itself?

Comment: Seems some clarification is in order.

1) I'm not looking for a magic button to be a generic unit test. I'm attempting to spark a discussion about testing all branches in a portion of code (multiple executions likely).  

2) "Intended path" would be the path we're attempting to test this execution.  

3) I do not believe all code has to test all possibilities, but I do believe some functions are important enough that testing all possibilities.  

The example above tests all paths in the testfunction.  Are there other methods people have used to complete test important sections.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for suggestions how to determine whether your tests have led to the execution of specific paths.  The obvious solution is to look for a tool that determines path coverage: The results of this coverage analysis would tell you, which paths have been taken and which not.  Such a tool, certainly, would do all that code-instrumenting for you.

Although I have not used any such tool yet, there seem to be some: http://archive.oreilly.com/cs/user/view/cs_msg/89669

But, there is one thing to keep in mind: If your code really is so critical that you care about path coverage, then just covering each path is not enough.  You should combine this approach with other techniques, like equivalence class partitioning and boundary case analysis - which will most likely lead to a number of different test cases for certain paths.